# When should I remove data from old host after completing the migration process?

Tags: wordpress, web, migration, hosting, web-hosting

Yesterday I manually migrated my website to another host. As my domain is in another company, hosting is in another and I wanted to move the hosting to another. So after transferring the data and updating the name server, my website is working fine as I've started receiving requests in new servers. Now I want to know when I can remove data from my old host and should I need to install WordPress on my my new host. As I moved it by copying all data and making folder by the same name to new host. Please help me on this.

Hosting was done manually

Comment: I suggest you to make a good backup of your website and remove all data from old host.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done a manual migration, uploaded the backup of your db onto your new database, changed the db details in wp-config, and changed the URL in the wp-options table in your db (can be done using phpMyAdmin), there is no need to add a new WordPress installation on your new hosting.

Note that after migrating this way, you should navigate to settings > permalinks (in your wp dashboard) and click save. Also, download [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) and replace all instances of your previous installation to the new server (in case the directory or anything in the URL has changed)

Comment: Thanks, I did the same as you mentioned and my links and URL are working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can compress all of WordPress's files in the root folder and upload it to the new web host. If you are keeping your old domain, you only need to export your database and upload it to the new web host. If you are changing domains (make sure to point the new domain to the new web host), you need to change your site's domain in Wp-admin > Permalink.

After that, you can remove data from the old host or request cancellation. Good Luck :D